# Generating branch instructions from an AST for a conditional expression

Tags: if-statement, compiler-construction, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to write a compiler for a domain-specific language, targeting a stack-machine based VM that is NOT a JVM.

I have already generated a parser for my language, and can readily produce an AST which I can easily walk.  I also have had no problem converting many of the statements of my language into the appropriate instructions for this VM, but am facing an obstacle when it comes to the matter of handling the generation of appropriate branching instructions when complex conditionals are encountered, especially when they are combined with (possibly nested) 'and'-like or 'or' like operations which should use short-circuiting branching as applicable.

I am not asking anyone to write this for me.   I know that I have not begun to describe my problem in sufficient detail for that.  What I am asking for is pointers to useful material that can get me past this hurdle I am facing.   As I said, I am already past the point of converting about 90% of the statements in my language into applicable instructions, but it is the handling of conditionals and generating the appropriate flow control instructions that has got me stumped.  Much of the info that I have been able to find so far on generating code from an AST only seems to deal with the generation of code corresponding to simple imperative-like statements, but the handing of conditionals and flow control appears to be much more scarce.

Other than the short-circuiting/lazy-evaluation mechanism for 'and' and 'or' like constructs that I have described, I am not concerned with handling any other optimizations.

Comment: Regarding resources, you can take a look at Crafting Interpreters, particularly the chapter [Jumping Back and Forth](http://www.craftinginterpreters.com/jumping-back-and-forth.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every conditional control flow can be modelled as a flow chart (or flow graph) in which the two branches of the conditional have different targets. Given that boolean operators short-circuit, they are control flow elements rather than simple expressions, and they need to be modelled as such.

One way to think about this is to rephrase boolean operators as instances of the ternary conditional operator. So, for example, `A and B` becomes `A ? B : false` and `A or B` becomes `A ? true : B` [Note 1]. Note that every control flow diagram has precisely two output points.
[image]

To combine boolean expressions, just substitute into the diagram. For example, here's `A AND (B OR C)`

[image]

You implement `NOT` by simply swapping the meaning of the two out-flows.

If the eventual use of the boolean expression is some kind of conditional, such as an `if` statement or a conditional loop, you can use the control flow as is. If the boolean expression is to be saved into a variable or otherwise used as a value, you need to fill in the two outflows with code to create the relevant constant, usually a **true** or **false** boolean constant, or (in C-like languages) a 1 or 0.

---

#### Notes:

1. Another way to write this equivalence is `A and B ⇒ A ? B : A`; `A or B ⇒ A ? A : B`, but that is less useful for a control flow view, and also clouds the fact that the intent is to only evaluate each expression once. This form (modified to reuse the initial computation of `A`) is commonly used in languages with multiple "falsey" values (like Python).